# mysql replace difficult conditions

Tags: php, mysql

a have 2 rows in db.table:

```
+79513028643+text@example.com
marin.nikulina2014+text@example.com
```

I need replace these email-address so

```
+79513028643@example.com
marin.nikulina2014@example.com
```

I made ​​such a request

```
update voters set email = concat( replace( substring_index(email, '@', 1), substring_index(substring(email, 2), '@', 1), substring_index(substring(email, 2), '+', 1) ),'@', substring_index(email, '@', -1)) WHERE voters.key regexp 'a78605bb9b9c5512ab3f7a06f73124ffcdafdddf|32a08a88001074fb59db19a3c3a83eb89f75a052'
```

after execution

```
+79513028643@example.com@example.com
marin.nikulina2014@example.com
```

look what happened to the first address
Please help make a query!
Thx!

upd some email addresses do not contain the symbol "+" 
upd(2) text after the sign "+" may be different

Comment: please describe your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     email = REPLACE(email, '+text', '')
WHERE   email REGEXP '+79513028643+text@example.com'
```

or you can use one of these:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(text, pattern [, mode])
REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, pattern [,position [,occurence [,mode]]])
REGEXP_INSTR?(text, pattern [,position [,occurence [,return_end [,mode]]]])
REGEXP_REPLACE?(text, pattern, replace [,position [,occurence [,return_end [,mode]]])
```

Comment: is not suitable because the text after the sign "+" may be different